# show loop id post , only first id can read

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop

I have a script , show post by id , and id post from array 
here my code :

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$f = cherry_get_option('blog-featured-post',false);
foreach ($f as $fs ) {
$q = new WP_Query( array(
'post__in' => array($fs),
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'asc'
 ) );}

 if ( $q->have_posts() ) : while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();
 //show post 
 the_title();
 endwhile; endif;
 endwhile; else:
 echo "no post found";
 endif;
 wp_reset_query();
```

nah from that code `$fs`will output id post what will display , 
i am try to `vardump($fs)` it work fine (the output is `string(4) "1254" string(4) "1310"`) but in `post_in` just first id can read (`string(4) "1254"`) I dont know what happen with my code , if anyone can help , i will happy

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: actually i just ask why , my code only just show 1 post , but actually if my code use `vardump($fs)` they will show 2 id

Comment: See my answer, if you need extra help, please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the option "blog-featured-post", which apparently returns two posts. Then, for each of these posts, you are making a query.

Only the second one is actually used, since your `if ( $q->have_posts() )` is outside of the loop. This query only has one post, since you use the post ID with the `post__in` option.

So this is expected behavior.

Comment: ohh ya i see , so `if ( $q->have_posts() )` is on the oustside my loop on `foreach` , and i just move `if ( $q->have_posts() )`into `foreach` right?

Comment: Yeah you could do that... basically move the bracket of the foreach loop to the end of the file.

Comment: xoxo , yeah its works , thankyou buddy